# Web scraping using VBA requires to show all nodes

Tags: python, html, excel, vba

I am unable to **scrape** complete data from a table on a website with around 1000 entries using

[image: IMG]

As seen in the image the code will require to show all nodes to **scrape** the complete data. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: Please, always inlcude your code and/or errors as text – otherwise it's not searchable. Further, please clarify how ___Python___ plays a role in your question (possibly remove that tag from your question). Then be as specific as possible (edit your question title and description accordingly); in particular add your VBA code and describe your problem/error in detail. You may also want to consult [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1040347) of text. They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question.